# Culture Info not changing when I click on link

Tags: c#, .net-core, cookies, cultureinfo

I want to be able to click on the link and instantly change the Culture/Language of my app. The problem is, when I click on the link, nothing happen. Clicking on the link, confirmed to change the cookie value (I checked). What am I missing here?

The Link:

```
<a href="/Language/SetLanguage?culture=en&returnUrl=@Context.Request.Path">English</a>
<a href="/Language/SetLanguage?culture=ms&returnUrl=@Context.Request.Path">Malay</a>
```

The Controller:

```
public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
{
    // Store the selected culture in a cookie or session
    Response.Cookies.Append("SelectedCulture", culture);
    Response.Cookies.Append("Language", culture);

    // Redirect back to the previous page or a specified return URL
    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

I set up services in program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("en"),
        new CultureInfo("ms")
    };

    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
}); 

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
       .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
       .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseRequestLocalization(app.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);
```

Comment: Is it not changing to English? There's a mistake in the English URL (no ampersand).

Comment: ampersand added. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I added this part so it can identify what cookie to look for (in this case, cookie named Language), and it solves the problem.

```
        // Custom middleware to set the current language based on the cookie
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var cultureCookie = context.Request.Cookies["Language"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cultureCookie))
            {
                var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(cultureCookie);
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
                CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
            }

            await next.Invoke();
        });
```